# FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API doesn't return any data by I_POSTING_DATES range

Tags: datetime, abap, saprfc, function-module

In `SE37`, I am trying to execute `FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API` function module but in import parameters area `I_POSTING_DATE` is not working and output brings all records to `BUDAT` column although I insert `01.05.2020 - 30.05.2020`. Complete input is:

- SIGN column -->I
- OPTION column -->BT
- LOW column -->01.05.2020
- HIGH column -->30.05.2020

My question is: What should be written inside of the `I_POSTING_DATES` column by column to get the data from `ET_FAGLPOSX` table as i want.

Thank you

[image: SE37 test of FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API]

Comment: The words "is not working" are meaningless, please explain why you consider it's wrong and what you expect to obtain.

Comment: Hi sandra, i am expecting output records to be between the dates that i gave in high and low column date. But in output, system brings all records just like i did not declare date in the I_POSTING_DATE table. After execution, i enter output in ET_FAGLPOSX table and i see budat column does not recognize my date range because BUDAT is posting date column and i am expecting to be filtered which i gave in LOW and HIGH column. Thanx

Comment: I think that `I_POSTING_DATES` is considered the same way as in transaction code `FAGLL03`, i.e. only with `I_KIND_OF_SELECTION = '3'` (all items).

Comment: Yes this is function module for FAGLL03 and this is working right now :) thanx sandra.

Comment: I can not vote you it is because i am under 15 reputation i think if there is any way to vote you please direct me.

Comment: I have converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of `FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API` reflect the ones in the selection screen of transaction code `FAGLL03`.

As you can see in `FAGLL03`, the selection by posting date is possible only when "All items" is selected:
[image: SAP FAGLL03 selection screen]

The parameter `I_KIND_OF_SELECTION` of `FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API` corresponds to the 3 radio buttons:

- `1` : Open items
- `2` : Cleared items
- `3` : All items

The selection by posting date is possible only if you select "all items", and it's the same with `FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API`, the parameter `I_POSTING_DATES` is considered only with `I_KIND_OF_SELECTION = '3'`.